# Read response that came before run script

Tags: javascript, post, get, request, response

For example, some not mine site. While page is loading, send request and return `response`. I can see it by Network tab (Ctrl + Shift + J, Chrome).

Now I want to run my script by hand into Console tab. I need to data that contain in `response`. I can find the data by hand and click `store as global variable` and then uses it.

Can I write some script that read the data into `response` that already exists by Network tab? The case with repeat request into script doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Not on your site? Quite difficult. If you find the line (on chrome),  you can set a breakpoint, edit the code right below, ctrl + s and run again. If you make `window.response = response` you should be able to access it from your console.